# Editing TextLabel in a UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to do edit-in-place in a UITableView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2803626/how-to-do-edit-in-place-in-a-uitableview)

I am new to this iphone developing.
I just want to know how to edit/update UITextLabel in a tableView.

I am already using edit/done animation and able to delete rows but i am not able to get how to  edit the text in those rows.

I want the user to edit the textlabel of the cell.when edit button is tapped.

i already searched the site but couldnt get the exact answer.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CellIdentifier"];
if(!cell)
{
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"CellIdentifier"]autorelease];
    cell.editingAccessoryType=YES;
}


myTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 6, 241, 31)];
myTextField.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
myTextField.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
myTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
myTextField.delegate = self;
cell.accessoryView = myTextField;
myTextField.text = [self.arrayOfItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
myTextField.enabled = NO;
return cell;
}

-(IBAction)Edit:(id)sender
{
if(self.editing)
{
            [myTextField.Enabled = YES];
    [super setEditing:NO animated:NO];
    [self.tab setEditing:NO animated:NO];
    [self.tab reloadData];
    [self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem setTitle:@"Done"];
    [self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem setStyle:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain];
}
else 
{
    myTextField.enabled= YES;

    [super setEditing:YES animated:YES];
    [self.tab setEditing:YES animated:YES];
    [self.tab reloadData];
    [self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem setTitle:@"Edit"];
    [self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem setStyle:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone];
 }
 }

- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
if (self.editing == NO || !indexPath) 
return UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;
if (self.editing && indexPath.row == ([self.arrayOfItems count])) 
{
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert;
} 
else 
{
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
}
return UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;
}
```

This is not working for me.textfield is disappearing if i hit edit button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Editing text in the table rows themselves is difficult because you need to manage the keyboard and scrolling the editable field up to make room for the keyboard etc. (that could be scrolled off screen while being edited etc.).  Also if you make every cell editable you have to managed an edited value being able to be scrolled off screen mid-edit etc. (i.e. while the keyboard is active and so forth).

A UILabel is not editable, you need a UITextField to edit text.

The best way to achieve an edit of a value in a table cell is probably to push a new view controller onto the stack on the edit action and have an editable text field there and add save/cancel bar button items to the menu of that view controller.

When the user presses save, update the model behind the table view with the appropriate text value and pop the view controller off the stack again. Have the main view containing the table call reloadData on the tableView in its viewWillAppear method.

This will give you easiest/best control of the keyboard behaviour and editing behaviour when the fields are being edited.

Comment: While this doesn't really answer the question of how to do in-table text edits, it does present some valid points for why it might not be a good idea in all circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

Use UITextField in place of UILabel in Your Custom cell,then You can edit.for custom cell You can check this [Tutorial](http://codenugget.org/customizing-table-view-cells-for-fancy-user-i)
or You can Check this [Apple Sample](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/CoreDataBooks/) also.

Comment: i am not sure about how to do it.can u post some code?

Comment: I have already edit my answer and given you a link for how to customize TableViewCell

Comment: If You got the solution from my answer then accept it.

Comment: i already have a textlabel and when user taps edit button the textlabel should be editable.

Comment: You can't edit the UILabel text.for your requirement You can replace UILabel with UITextField.

Comment: ya thats what i want to know how?.how to display text in the textfield.and make it uneditable  and how to make it editable when a button is pressed.

Comment: firstly you can set the editing property of textfield to NO.and after tap on edit button you can set it to Yes.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the standard UITableViewCell, you can do the following:

```
//Get the first cell of the first section
NSIndexPath *ip = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:ip];

//Change the textLabel contents
[[cell textLabel] setText@"Updated text"];

//Refresh the tableView
[tableView reloadData];
```

Comment: i want to edit the textLabel dynamically when the edit button is pressed.

Comment: This does let you do that. 

TIP don't run "tableView reloadData" as that will override the cell animation when you transition to edit mode.

Answer (score -3):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
.........

cell.textLabel.text = @"my text";

return cell;
}
```

Comment: That's not quite what he wants.

Comment: i want to edit/update the textLabel.

Comment: So you want to change the `textLabel` of the `UITableCell` in your code or you want the user to be able to edit the cell text?

Comment: i want the user to be able to edit the cell text

Comment: add transparent button on cell (textlabel), add selector fot it. In selector open alertview with textfield for edit, save new text to data model, refresh table view. There are many ways to solve this. did you try to add textfield to cell?

Comment: yes i added textField and when i hit edit button.the whole textfield is disappearing.All i can see is a red button with which we can delete rows