# editing contents of UITableViewCells

Tags: uitableview

I have seen (especially with iBooks) that you could edit a line in a table view without using a "sub-screen". I know how to delete or insert a line but I've been searching on the  Net for the way for editing an existing line. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to [so], Patrick.  Would it be possible to edit your question to provide a little more detail? For example, is this for Mac or iOS?  Are you using custom (and subclassed) table view cells or just default ones?

Comment: Hi Micheal. Thank ypu for your asking for precisions. I am programming on IOS and my question was nabout default table view cells.

Comment: what do you want to edit in these cells?  some text or something else?

Comment: Just plain text. To be more precise, I need to deal with sites (just text) and names of participants.

Comment: In two different tables obviously.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Editing TextLabel in a UITableViewCell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9209661/editing-textlabel-in-a-uitableviewcell)

Comment: There's actually a number of questions in [so] that have good answers you can use.  Such as [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9209661/editing-textlabel-in-a-uitableviewcell) and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4123740/in-place-editing-of-text-in-uitableviewcell).  You'll definitely need to do a custom UITableViewCell though, since the default cells have labels and not (editable) text fields.

Comment: Thanks for not deleting my question. I will study the answerers suggested and edit for more details if they does'nt match what I'm looking for.